# Menu Not Showing on Mobile

Tags: menus, mobile

I am using the latest version of wordpress with the responsive theme. The drop down menu doesnt show on mobile - or when the browser window is very small. Its the drop down menu that is three lines. When you click it, it should have a drop down menu.

It works fine on a full desktop screen - but when I shrink the screen (or view it on mobile), the three lines menu does create a drop down. Nothing happens when you click it. Here is the link. Anyone have any ideas.

http://itmemes.com

Just open on mobile browser

Comment: You should ask the theme developer.

Answer (score 1):

Your menu on mobile have font color white. check the attached image below.

go to your theme setting and then menu or mobile menu setting. change the color to #000 or black.

[image]

Comment: accept the answer as solved and vote up =D Cheer